# How to append Text in TextBox using MVC?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having one textbox & i already added some value to that text box, When i select one string in menu,that string also append to that textbox in MVC ??how it is Possible???
please Help ME

Comment: Please, show us some code with definitions of those controls.

Comment: Do you write all code myself or use third party solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most quick and easy way is to use select event ( or click ) event of the menu , and take its text and append it to your textbox text using jquery. Thanks